# Does anyone know a good MSI Log Viewer?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

Fairly simple question, does anyone know of good utility for browsing msi log files?

Be interested in anything that provides filtering, a nice view of different standard and custom actions, action sequencing, properties, and errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I found [the tip from Rob Mensching about the first thing to look for in the MSI log](https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/) very useful, much more useful than any tool for log viewing. To be honest, I rarely have to look for anything beyond this.

As for the true log file parsing, only the verbose log file contains enough info to understand what's going on, hence if you need to walk through (a big part of) the whole process of the installation (not only a place the error occurs in), be ready to read the log line by line, because almost every line matters, as well as the sequence. If you need to track the value of the property, just open the log file and Ctrl+F that property name to see its evolution during the installation.

BTW, do you know that [WiX can be even more verbose](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/07/15/verbose-logging-from-wcautil/)? :-)

Comment: I find searching for "**value 3**" to be the best approach as well. I have [a little blurb for people who ask about logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028367/129130). I recommend [**the annotated MSI log by Robert Macdonald**](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916030949/http://www.rmacdonald.members.winisp.net/Blog_Docs/Annotated_Windows_Installer_Log.pdf) from the dissolved Windows Installer Team (resurrected link  from Wayback Machine - it is broken in his blog). There is also "[Log Parser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx)" (haven't had the time to try it).

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [Wilogutl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372811%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Also, see this article for a basic usage: http://dennisbareis.com/makemsi-manual/view_verbose_msi_log.htm

Here's another good one: http://www.hoschi.biz/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=44&Itemid=53

Comment: Yes I've tried WiLogUtl.exe and wasnt overly impressed tbh.  I'll certainly take a look at the other link though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried LogGrok for viewing MSI logs?

It supports filter the log by any field for MSI, VB and NLOG, configurable highlighteres(some are already pre-configured), multiple search results (supporting Regex).

Utility supports large log files and has customizable docking windows UI.

LogGrok is opensource, you can add features you need by yourself(or ask project team to add it for you). Project documentation can be found at https://loggrok.codeplex.com/