# Website is not getting created in IIS - limited edition of InstallShield

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, installation, installshield, installshield-le

I am using Limited Edition of InstallShield 2015 with Visual Studio 2015.

I have configured **Internet information Services settings** as shown below, but website is not getting created in IIS.

[image]

My IIS version is: 10.0

Here is the IIS settings inside **InstallShield**

[image]

Note: Source code is successfully copies ***[INSTALLDIR]*** of destination computer but it's not getting mapped with IIS.

**Updates**

I see only declaration related to IIS, but not used anywhere in log!

```
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_CREATEAPPPOOL = Creating application pool %s
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_CREATEAPPPOOLS = Creating application Pools...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_CREATEVROOT = Creating IIS virtual directory %s
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_CREATEVROOTS = Creating IIS virtual directories...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_CREATEWEBSERVICEEXTENSION = Creating web service extension
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_CREATEWEBSERVICEEXTENSIONS = Creating web service extensions...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_CREATEWEBSITE = Creating IIS website %s
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_CREATEWEBSITES = Creating IIS websites...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_EXTRACT = Extracting information for IIS virtual directories...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_EXTRACTDONE = Extracted information for IIS virtual directories...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_EXTRACTDONEz = Extracted information for IIS virtual directories...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_EXTRACTzDONE = Extracted information for IIS virtual directories...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_REMOVEAPPPOOL = Removing application pool
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_REMOVEAPPPOOLS = Removing application pools...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_REMOVESITE = Removing web site at port %d
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_REMOVEVROOT = Removing IIS virtual directory %s
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_REMOVEVROOTS = Removing IIS virtual directories...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_REMOVEWEBSERVICEEXTENSION = Removing web service extension
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_REMOVEWEBSERVICEEXTENSIONS = Removing web service extensions...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_REMOVEWEBSITES = Removing IIS websites...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_ROLLBACKAPPPOOLS = Rolling back application pools...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_ROLLBACKVROOTS = Rolling back virtual directory and web site changes...
     Property(S): PROGMSG_IIS_ROLLBACKWEBSERVICEEXTENSIONS = Rolling back web service extensions...
```

**Resolved**

After adding APPLICATION inside WEBSITE issue has been resolved. Seems like just having WEBSITE in InstallShield is not enough.

Comment: Check the setup.exe command line I updated below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by adding a **Application** inside **Website**.

Seems like just having **Website** in **Configure the Target System->Internet Information Services** is not enough.

Reason: InstallShield Limited Version does not support creating website outside default web sites.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ***Improved?***: [**Different ways to create and interpret MSI logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890).

---

Nice effort to create a comprehensible question, but I am afraid you forgot the most important part: **what does the log file say?** Please update your question with details.

I am adding this as an answer, and I will "evolve" it once we get more information.

Here is my standard blurb on logging for you for a start:

### Logging your MSI-Install

Here is how to log your install (silent install):

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\Installer.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"
```

or for a setup.exe:

```
Setup.exe /v"/l*v C:\msilog.log /QN"
```

Quick Parameter Explanation:

```
/I = run regular installation sequence
/QN = run completely silently
/L*V "C:\My.log" = verbose logging at specified path
```

If this is confusing [try installsite.org's logging FAQ](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm) - how to create a log file for your installation.

- Once you have a log, you can [**search for "value 3"** in the log file as explained by Rob Mensching here](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/). In your case the install seems to have completed successfully, so you need to look for warnings and suppressed errors as well.
- This article from **Robert Macdonald** - from the long-since dissolved Windows Installer Team -
  is highly recommended as a practical look at MSI logging: [**How to Interpret Windows Installer Logs**](http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2007/04/02/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs.aspx).

  - There is a broken link in that blog to a PDF / Word file with **an annotated MSI log** in it. [**Here it is resurrected from WayBack Machine**](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916030949/http://www.rmacdonald.members.winisp.net/Blog_Docs/Annotated_Windows_Installer_Log.pdf).
- [Wilogutl.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/wilogutl-exe) - the Microsoft SDK MSI log viewer. Not the greatest thing, but has its uses. [Discussion of its use](http://dennisbareis.com/makemsi-manual/view_verbose_msi_log.htm).

---

***Some Links***:

- [Does anyone know a good MSI Log Viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915005/does-anyone-know-a-good-msi-log-viewer) (cross-linking)
- [The full range of msiexec.exe command line options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx). Here is [the technet version](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490936.aspx).

Comment: What project type is this? Installscript MSI? Installscript (legacy non-MSI)? Basic MSI? go `Project => Settings... => Type field` - it should say the project type. I added the command line above that you can use to enable logging for a `setup.exe` install that is MSI-based.

Comment: Yes, Its InstallShield MSI. Log generated. I have updated the log. Log is huge. How can I upload?

Comment: Most people seem to use https://www.dropbox.com for log file upload, I have never used it myself unfortunately. Did you search for "**value 3**" in the log file as suggested above? Also try to search for "Error" and maybe "IIS". In Installshield, are the IIS components added to a proper feature? You can see component / feature assignment in "Setup Design". You can also go to the "Components" view and check if there are any red exclamation icons (component is not assigned to any features)?

Comment: There is no "error", no "value 3".  Code is successfully copied to destination folder but IIS is not creating the website. I doubt it's some mapping issue in configuration.

Comment: OK, have you tried the setup on another box? Just to eliminate any machine-specific issues? I am not familiar with the LE editions of Installshield. [**The WiX toolkit**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) (free, open source) may give you more flexibility for IIS installations. Fiddly to set up, but great when you get it working (full flexibility & control). [**Sample**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application) (not tested by me, looks OK).

Comment: Let me give a try. keep you posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165976/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-codetoshare).

Comment: Resolved.After adding APPLICATION inside WEBSITE issue has been resolved. Seems like just having WEBSITE in InstallShield is not enough.

Comment: @codetoshare, so glad to hear that your issue is solved, you can add a reply and mark it, that will help other community members to easier search this helpful information, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I created another website outside default website in InstallShield Evaluation version 2010. I changed the TCP Port Number to 8080.

[image]

[image]