# InstallShield installer error 2006 with GUI installer

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield, installshield-2012

I am trying to run an installer built using InstallShield, and when using the installer in Windows 2008, it works as intended; the same installer running in Windows 2012R2, fails with the message

**Installer User Interface mode Not Supported**

The installer cannot run in this UI mode.  To specify the interface mode, use the I-command-line option, followed by the UI mode identifier.  The valid UI modes identifiers are GUI, Console, and Silent.

I am running as Administrator, and I tried using the Compatibility Mode, but I still get the same error. I checked the InstallShield project and it does have the default Windows UI mode to GUI. What causes this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: This issue could be due to non-alphanumeric symbols in the path to installer or %temp% folder.

Comment: [**Some logging hints here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028367/129130). Create a log and have a look.

Answer (score 0):

***Terminal Server***: Is this a terminal server machine? Not my field, but there is a difference between **`Execution Mode`** and **`Installation Mode`** on Terminal Servers.

***From ITProToday*** ([source)](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/how-do-i-install-applications-use-terminal-server): *Installing applications on a terminal server has to be done in a special way to ensure it is usable by all users of the terminal server...There are two modes in terminal server, Execute and Install. By default all users are logged on in **Execute mode** and this means they can run programs etc. When you want to install an Application for use by everyone the Administrator should change to **Install mode**.*

***Change.exe***: https://ss64.com/nt/change.html

---

***Add / Remove Programs***: Do you install through the **Control Panel Add/Remove Programs tool**? Or do you use the command **`"Change User /Install"`** at a prompt? If you use this command, you should return to normal execution mode by using the command **`"Change User /Execute"`** after installing the application.

---

***Some Links***:

- **https://ss64.com/nt/change.html**
- [**Using Install mode instead of Execute mode**](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ServerAutomation/83/installing/performing-the-installation/installing-bmc-server-automation-on-windows/using-install-mode-instead-of-execute-mode)
- [When you toggle Terminal Services to Application Server mode, some programs may stop working](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/252330/when-you-toggle-terminal-services-to-application-server-mode-some-prog)