# Setup.msi, gives error on creating instance of Custom Action Installer Class

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, installation

I have a issue with a setup file created in Visual Studio Project Installer.
Previously I created an installer, that just copies the files to the indicated location, without any custom action.

Now I created a new setup file, with a custom action installer class.

When I try to run the new installer on a machine where was installed the old version of the application, during the installation popups an error:

> Error 1001. Unable to create an instance of Namespace.InstallerCustomAction installer type. --> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

If I run the installer on a machine that haven't use the old version of the application that doesn't have custom actions, is installing without any problem.

Also, I always uninstall the old version of the application before installing new one. Checked the Registry, nothing remains in it about the old version.
The RAM and DISK memory is more than enough. I tried also to change the Product and Package code...I get the same error. In fact, if the Product code is different, should not have any conflict even if the old version is installed.

[image]

Does anyone had this type of error ever?

Comment: Enable logging and check what's happening at the moment of the error.

Comment: Enabled, looking now in the log file.

Comment: [Tips For Checking MSI Log Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026782/website-is-not-getting-created-in-iis-limited-edition-of-installshield/49028367#49028367).

Comment: Is your MSI 32-bit or 64? Is the assembly compiled for "x86" or "Any CPU" or something else?

Comment: Any CPU. Used to install it on x64 System.

Comment: Too busy to look at this. But here is [my propaganda piece against Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944893/129130). [Alternative tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130). WiX is free. Learning curve.

Comment: Some more info about this problem... On my computer also stopped working, but at the end of the day, the installer started to work again. I don't have anything in the background that can stop the install process. Also, is possible to have a policy in domain that stops the install of unpublished projects/setups?