# Issues with uninstall program in control panel built with WiX toolset

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm creating msi installer that run services with auto start for windows using wix toolset. msi was successfully compiled and installed, and services are working correctly.

The problem is that, when i try to uninstall the program in control panel, it's showing the following message:

[image: problem]

I tried to remove the program from regedit and tried to install using the command:

```
MsiExec /I installer.msi REINSTALLMODE=voums REINSTALL=ALL
```

Here is the code of product and package declarations:

```
<Product Name='Foobar 1.0' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.' Id='6DA5C23A-86C7-4D14-AEC0-86416A69ABDE' UpgradeCode='6DA5C23A-7349-453F-94F6-BCB5110BA4FD' Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='1.0.0'>
    <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="Acme's Foobar 1.0 Installer" Comments='Foobar is a registered trademark of Acme Ltd.' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.' InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />
```

In `INSTALLDIR`, i have an exe file for service, and do some actions:

```
<Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='Foobar 1.0'>

    <Component Id='ConfPathEnv' Guid='6DA5C23A-6BE3-460D-A14F-75658D16550B' KeyPath="yes">
        <Environment Id="AQLIGHT_CONFIG_PATH" Name="AQLIGHT_CONFIG_PATH" Value="[INSTALLDIR]config.json" Permanent="yes" Part="last" Action="set" System="yes" />
    </Component>

    <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='6DA5C23A-83F1-4F22-985B-FDB3C8ABD471'>
        <File Id='serviceEXE' Name='service.exe' DiskId='1' Source='service.exe' KeyPath='yes' />
        <ServiceInstall Id="InstallService" Name="AqLightService" DisplayName="AqLightService 1.0" Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" Arguments="install" Type="ownProcess" />
        <ServiceControl Id="ControlService" Name="AqLightService" Start="install" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
    </Component>

</Directory>
```

In order to remove folder when uninstalling the program, i use the following code:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Foobar 1.0">
        <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="6DA5C23A-7E98-44CE-B049-C477CC0A2B00">
            <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
            <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I tried to change the GUIDs for each componet several times, but it did't help.

Comment: Does this happen on a clean test machine, a developer machine or a user machine? A clean test machine helps when there is something plainly wrong with the installer and is easiest to diagnose and fix. A developer machine is nice when it works but can become a problem itself. A user machine could find more real-world problems but the odd one could be not worth the time to diagnose.

Comment: @TomBlodget, thank you for your comment. Found the problem with logging and the problem is due to CustomAction. It is running during uninstall process, so that's why it's causing problem.

Comment: Failures during uninstall are almost always custom actions.  Hopefully you were testing on a clean VM or a machine you can reimage.  Getting a failed install off of a machine is fun but doable.

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

***Custom Action***: That error message can mean a number of things, but most commonly it is caused by a failing custom action. However, in this case it looks like the message is from **iTunes**?

***Logging***: No two ways about it: you need a verbose log file to try and make sense of this (adjust paths as appropriate):

```
msiexec.exe /x "Setup.msi" /L*V "C:\Setup.log"
```

> ***Self-Repair?***: My guess is that you have a corrupted machine / Windows Installer Database, or a self-repair problem that you have
>   turned into a corrupt machine by hacking the registry. Maybe. [On Self-Repair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53734308/129130).

---

***Conditioning***: When you need conditions to run only at certain times / installation modes - you need to deal with conditioning. There are many previous answers on MSI conditions. They are always hard to get right and testing is essential. Please see the answers below for information:

- ["MSI Condition Cheat Sheet"](https://www.flexerasoftware.com/webdocuments/PDF/IS-CHS-Common-MSI-Conditions.pdf)
- [Wix custom uninstallation action - how to run before msi removing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912568/wix-custom-uninstallation-action-how-to-run-before-msi-removing-files/50917907#50917907)
- **[How to execute conditional custom action on install and modify only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370505/how-to-execute-conditional-custom-action-on-install-and-modify-only/52377800#52377800)** - tip on how to test conditions using VBScript and the MSI API call "EvaluateCondition" at runtime - ze proof izt in ze pudding! :-).

This condition might be enough for you (no guarantees):

```
NOT Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE
```

Please test in all installation modes: : **`install`**, **`uninstall`**, **`modify`**, **`repair`**, **`self-repair`**, **`patching`**, **`major upgrade`**, **`etc...`**. Hard to tell how things can conspire, no substitute for real-world testing (just to state the obvious).

---

Here are more details on logging and interpreting the log file:

- [**Installsite.org on logging**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm)
- [**Interpreting MSI log files, etc...**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026782/website-is-not-getting-created-in-iis-limited-edition-of-installshield/49028367#49028367)
- [Event logging, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983606/visual-studio-installer-fails-on-aspnetdiagnosticpack-msi/49987350#49987350)
- [And another answer on logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55921746/129130).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Logging shows that the error occured because of CustomAction. Actually, i don't need to execute the Custom action during uninstall process. I'm wondering, how can i skip the execution of CustomAction when uninstalling the program.

Comment: Can we ask what the custom action is doing? And why it invokes iTunes? You need to condition the custom action properly so it only occurs in the right installation mode. `NOT Installed` means it runs only during fresh installation and in the new version being installed during major upgrades. `NOT Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` means it runs only during fresh installation and NOT in the new version being installed during major upgrades. Conditions are very complicated to get right. Testing is essential. See updated content above (in a few moments).

Comment: Thank you very much sir! The conditions for custom actions really helped.

Comment: Any luck finding out why that kicks of iTunes?

Comment: In order to show the error message, i just copied similar screen URL from the Internet and the first one was iTunes screen:)

Comment: OK, that explains things. I asked because it can indicate several other problems.